# PySpark aggregation function for "any value"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, coalesce

I have a PySpark Dataframe with an `A` field, few `B` fields that dependent on `A` (`A->B`) and `C` fields that I want to aggregate per each A. For example:

```
A | B | C
----------
A | 1 | 6
A | 1 | 7
B | 2 | 8
B | 2 | 4
```

I wish to group by `A` , present any of `B` and run aggregation (let's say `SUM`) on `C`.

The expected result would be:

```
A | B | C
----------
A | 1 | 13
B | 2 | 12
```

SQL-wise I would do:

```sql
SELECT A, COALESCE(B) as B, SUM(C) as C
FROM T
GROUP BY A
```

What is the PySpark way to do that?

I can group by A and B together or select `MIN(B)` per each A, for example:

```py
df.groupBy('A').agg(F.min('B').alias('B'),F.sum('C').alias('C'))
```

or

```
df.groupBy(['A','B']).agg(F.sum('C').alias('C'))
```

but that seems inefficient. Is there is anything similar to SQL `coalesce` in PySpark?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll just need to use `first` instead :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first, sum, col
from pyspark.sql import Row

array = [Row(A="A", B=1, C=6),
         Row(A="A", B=1, C=7),
         Row(A="B", B=2, C=8),
         Row(A="B", B=2, C=4)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(array))

results = df.groupBy(col("A")).agg(first(col("B")).alias("B"), sum(col("C")).alias("C"))
```

Let's now check the results :

```
results.show()
# +---+---+---+
# |  A|  B|  C|
# +---+---+---+
# |  B|  2| 12|
# |  A|  1| 13|
# +---+---+---+
```

**From the comments:**

> Is `first` here is computationally equivalent to `any` ?

`groupBy` causes shuffle. Thus a **non deterministic** behaviour is to expect.

Which is confirmed in the documentation of `first` :

> Aggregate function: returns the first value in a group.
>   The function by default returns the first values it sees. It will return the first non-null value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to true. If all values are null, then null is returned.
>   note:: The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on order of rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

So **yes**, computationally there are the same, and that's one of the reasons you need to use sorting if you need a deterministic behaviour.

I hope this helps !

Comment: Is ``first`` here is computationally equivalent to ``any`` ? I'm using this function a lot when doing a window (over partition order by) but then it requires sorting

Answer (score 1):

New in Spark 3.5.0:

You can use the aggregation function `any_value` to accomplish this.

Reusing @eliasah's answer with this new function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import any_value, sum, col
from pyspark.sql import Row

array = [Row(A="A", B=1, C=6),
         Row(A="A", B=1, C=7),
         Row(A="B", B=2, C=8),
         Row(A="B", B=2, C=4)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(array))

results = df.groupBy(col("A")).agg(any_value(col("B")).alias("B"), sum(col("C")).alias("C"))
```